# Inserting json file data to mysql using knex with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, knex.js

Working on inserting data to mysql using knex js with node js. I have json file in aws s3 bucket after that try to read json file and importing into mysql database. the code is working on local machine but after deployment to lambda function code is not working. Not getting any error

```
import fs from "fs";
import JSONStream from 'JSONStream';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const test2 = async (req : any, res: any, db2 : any) => {
   var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'bucketname',
            Key: 'state.json'
        }
        const data =await s3.getObject(params).promise();
}
const getData = (data :any,db2 : any)=>{
    const test = data.Body.toString();
    fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/' + 'state.json', test);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/' + 'state.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})
    delay(5000);
    try{
    stream
      .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
      .on('data',async (data : any) => {
            stream.pause();
            db2('tablename').insert(data)
                  .then((res:any) => {
                        stream.resume()
                        console.log(res)
                  })
      });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("err",err)
    }
     delay(2000);  
}
 
export default test2;
```

above code is working in local but after deployment to lambda function then this code is not working

Using Node js, Knex js.
db2 has connection through knex js to mysql

Answer (score 0):

I find the fix of this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            stream.pipe(streamParser).on("data", async streamData => {
                const res1 = await db2(tablename).insert(data);
                return console.log(await res1);
            }).on("finish", () => {
                console.log("STREAM FINISH!");
                resolve(true);
            }).on("error", e => {
                console.error("Stream error:", e);
                reject(e);
            });
        });
```